# How to make access database for user of joomla 2.5 after login

Tags: joomla

I know joomla has login facility. With that login, I can edit or else. But, I want to make that login facility can access some database when user guest loged in. Please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You would usually want to access the database from a component.

As your question is as vague as it can get, the only thing I can tell you is to visit the documentation on [Component Development](http://docs.joomla.org/Component_Development)